# Which one is correct and natural sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I've got 2 options for sentences here:

1. I visit my hometown about two or three times a year.
2. I visit my hometown about twice or three times a year.

Which one is correct and natural?

Answer (score -3):

The first sentence should be..

"I visit my hometown about two or three times a year"

While in the second sentence maybe  grammatically incorrect

It should be
"I visit my hometown twice or thrice a year

See
 http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/twice

Comment: Both sentence are grammatically correct.

Comment: It's more logical to say 'two or three times', but I can imagine someone starting to say 'twice', thinking to themselves 'Perhaps it's more often than that' and adding '...or three times.'

Comment: @HotLicks: Thanks for your comment, which one should I use in  English Spoken language?